# .htaccess - affects all subdomains, how to exclude?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
#Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^raal.co.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.raal.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|JPG|png|css|php|js|html|htm|psd|rar|htc)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

but then when i create subdomains, i get an error due to this code.

I want - fb.raal.co.il - to not be affected by the .htaccess of the main path.

i've tried adding something like this to the main .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fb\.raal\.co\.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://fb.raal.co.il/$1
```

but it wont work ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just negate (!) that you dont want to redirect fb

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^raal\.co\.il
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fb\.raal\.co\.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.raal.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can use multiple conditions (RewriteCond) for just one RewriteRule

and use `\.` instead of `.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^raal\.co\.il
```

dot is a one character in regex